# Can SimpleDraweeView be used with uri's which return svg images?

Tags: android, fresco

I was using `SimpleDraweeView` to set image from a uri in android, and the uri when hit returns image which has `content-type` as `image/svg+xml` instead of `image/jpeg`. My question is that whether SimpleDraweeView can be used for such case?

Answer (score 1):

Fresco supports custom image decoders. An example on how to implement such a decoder for SVG support can be found here: https://github.com/facebook/fresco/tree/master/samples/showcase/src/main/java/com/facebook/fresco/samples/showcase/imageformat/svg

Documentation how to use custom decoders: http://frescolib.org/docs/customizing-image-formats.html